# Extracting [0-9_]+ from a URL

Tags: python, regex

I've put together the following regular expression to extract image ID's from a URL:

```
''' Parse the post details from the full story page '''
def parsePostFromPermalink(session, permalink):

    r = session.get('https://m.facebook.com{0}'.format(permalink))
    dom = pq(r.content)

    # Parse the images, extract the ID's, and construct large image URL
    images = []
    for img in dom('a img[src*="jpg"]').items():
        if img.attr('src'):
            m = re.match(r'/([0-9_]+)n\.jpg/', img.attr('src'))
            images.append(m)
    return images
```

URL example:

```
https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/cp0/e15/q65/s200x200/13645330_275977022775421_8826465145232985957_n.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&oh=ed5b4593ed9c8b6cfe683f9c6932acc7&oe=57EE1224
```

I want this bit:

```
13645330_275977022775421_8826465145232985957
```

I've tested it on regex101 and it works: https://regex101.com/r/eS6eS7/2

`img.attr('src')` contains the correct URL and is not empty. I tested this. When I try to use `m.group(0)` I get an exception that `group` is not a function. `m` is `None`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes. Your regular expression contain `/` characters that do not belong there. They're just separators in some other languages such as javascript. Use `r'([0-9_]+)n\.jpg'`

Comment: Ah and that `match` is true as well.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Ah. I wish all languages used the same syntax. Works now.

Comment: @love2node they use for regular expressions, but `/` does **not** belong to the regular expression. In Python, POSIX C, Java, the regular expressions are given in a string. In some other languages there are special syntactic sugar for regular expression literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

- those enclosing `/.../` are not a part of [Python regex syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)
- you should use [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) instead of [`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match)

Working example:

```
>>> url = "https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/cp0/e15/q65/s200x200/13645330_275977022775421_8826465145232985957_n.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&oh=ed5b4593ed9c8b6cfe683f9c6932acc7&oe=57EE1224"
>>> re.search(r'([0-9_]+)n\.jpg', url).group(0)
'13645330_275977022775421_8826465145232985957_n.jpg'
```

If you want just the number part, use this (`group(1)`, and note the additional `_`):

```
>>> re.search(r'([0-9_]+)_n\.jpg', url).group(1)
'13645330_275977022775421_8826465145232985957'
```

Comment: Care to explain why search over match? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct python code from Regex101. (There's a code generator on the left). Notice the lack of slashes on the outside of the regex...

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'([\d_]+)n\.jpg')
test_str = u"https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/cp0/e15/q65/c3.0.103.105/p110x80/13700209_937389626383181_6033441713767984695_n.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&oh=a0b90ec153211eaf08a6b7c4cc42fb3b&oe=581E2EB8"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

I'm not sure how you got `m` as None, but you might need to compile the pattern and use that to match first.    Otherwise, try to fix the expression first